# Get next availbalility for a reservation

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables on my database. Table one is called "courts" and table 2 is "reservations".

The court table has id, name of court, opening: time the court is available and closing: time when last reservation must finish

courts

```
id, name, opening, closing
1, court_1, 08:00, 22:00
2, court_2, 08:00, 23:00
```

The reservations table has id, court_id: the court in which the reservation is taking place, datetime: the date and the time of a reservation, duration: the duration of the reservation in minutes

reservations

```
id, court_id, datetime, duration
1, 2, 2019-10-28 14:30, 90
2, 1, 2019-10-28 17:15, 60
```

I am trying to build an sql query that will return the first available court for reservation. The reservation start time will be today, 30 minutes from now, it will have a default duration of 60 minutes and it should be between the opening and closing time of the court.

Comment: could you post your solution also..

Comment: Which Database engine you are using? Oracle,MySQL, MS SQL etc.,?

Comment: The database engine is Mysql

Comment: select * from `courts` where `courts`.`id` not in
(select `court_id` from `reservations` where CAST(`datetime` AS DATE)='2019-10-29' )
This is my solution so far.But its not even half way through. I have to figure out how to get a court that doesn't have a reservation after 30 minutes from now and for a duration of 60 minutes

Comment: Oh, maybe I misunderstood: you just need to find which courts are available for that given time, i.e. the answer is "courts 1 and 2"? Or are you trying to find the next possible booking for each court, e.g. "court 1 at 16:00, court 2 at 15:00" ? If it's the first, you just need to `select * from courts where <booking within opening hours> and not exists (select * from reservations where reservations.court_id = court.id and <booking overlaps existing reservation>)` (I'm leaving the `<>` bits for you to fill in)

Comment: Yes exaclty. I am trying to find the next possible booking for each court. Once I find them I can sort them by time and limit to 1 to get the next reservation

Comment: OK, then I think the problem you're trying to solve is finding a gap in a sequence in SQL. If you search for that (e.g. [lots of discussion here](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/the-sql-of-gaps-and-islands-in-sequences/)) then the simplest solution seems to be to generate a sequence and filter it, e.g. generate a sequence of every 15 minutes from now + 30 to max(closing for today) - duration, then join that against each court and where-not-exists existing reservations that overlap.

Comment: Thanks Rup for the tip. I have no idea of how to generate this sequence and filter it. I will look in to this attached article to see if I can figure this out